# Working example of two-factor authentication using smart card and pcsc-lite?

Tags: linux, smartcard

I have a laptop (Dell) with a smart card reader. I'm trying to get it to do two-factor authentication with Linux. Here's the hardware:

```
$ opensc-tool -n
Using reader with a card: Broadcom 5880 [Broadcom USH] (0123456789ABCD) 00 00
Cryptoflex 32K e-gate v4
```

It seems to read the card fine, but following the [opensc directions](http://www.opensc-project.org/opensc/wiki/QuickStart) I can get a key, but it has a strange ID.

```
$ pkcs15-tool  -k
Using reader with a card: Broadcom 5880 [Broadcom USH] (0123456789ABCD) 00 00
Private RSA Key [Private Key]
        Object Flags   : [0x3], private, modifiable
        Usage          : [0x4], sign
        Access Flags   : [0x1D], sensitive, alwaysSensitive, neverExtract, local
        ModLength      : 2048
        Key ref        : 0 (0x0)
        Native         : yes
        Path           : 3f0050154b0130000012
        Auth ID        : 01
        ID             : 2d4dce07ca7a666723df7cff307abf7825a31be1
        GUID           : {2d4dce07-ca7a-6667-23df-7cff307abf78}
```

Then, trying to use it always produces an error.

```
12 $ pkcs15-tool -r 45
Using reader with a card: Broadcom 5880 [Broadcom USH] (0123456789ABCD) 00 00
Certificate with ID '45' not found.
13 $ pkcs15-tool -r 2d4dce07ca7a666723df7cff307abf7825a31be1
Using reader with a card: Broadcom 5880 [Broadcom USH] (0123456789ABCD) 00 00
Certificate with ID '2d4dce07ca7a666723df7cff307abf7825a31be1' not found.
```

I'm kind of stuck here. Anyone know how to get past this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a *keypair*, but not a *certificate* (-r will read a *certificate*)  You can read the *public key* with

`pkcs15-tool --read-public-key 2d4dce07ca7a666723df7cff307abf7825a31be1`